# From string to integer Javascript

Tags: javascript

```js
function FinalAmount() {
  var FinalPrice = document.getElementById("FinalPrice");
  let AllProductTotalPrice = 0;

  for (let index = 0; index < OrderedProductList.length; ++index) {
    alert;
    var CurrentProductTotal = 0;
    CurrentProductTotal = OrderedProductList[index].TotalPrice;
    console.log(CurrentProductTotal);
    AllProductTotalPrice += CurrentProductTotal;
    console.log(AllProductTotalPrice);
  }
  FinalAllProductPrice = AllProductTotalPrice;
  FinalPrice.innerText = "RM" + FinalAllProductPrice;
}
```

This is my javascript code. I would have a question about why the console.log(CurrentProductTotal) is already an integer but the above AllProductTotalPrice is a string value. Is there any way to let its sum as an integer and bring it to the below FinalAllProductPrice. Please help me TT

Comment: `TotalPrice` may not be a number value, you can try to parse it to a number like `Number(OrderedProductList[index].TotalPrice)`

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to show examples of what is logged? What you're saying doesn't seem possible

Comment: @Nick Vu Thanks this is the solution to the question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the easiest way would be to

use `Number()` to parse a string to a number. (we don't define integers specifically in javascript)

```js
const num = "1234"
Number(num)
```

⚠️ If you give it a string which does not solely consist out of numbers it will return `NaN`

So in your example that would be:

```js
CurrentProductTotal = OrderedProductList[index].TotalPrice
```

Now to your questions:

- `console.log()` automatically displays it formatted for you. I would use the `typeof` operator to check whether `CurrentProductTotal` is really a number, or a string which the console formats differently which is a bit confusing.

Try this in your browser console:

```js
const num = "1234"
> undefined
num
> '1234'
console.log(num)
> 1234 // formatted like a number
console.log(num, typeof num)
> 1234 string // still formatted like a number, but a string in reality
```